# Image display using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

i need jquery for images display like in the below URL.

http://www.yessy.com/sujatatibre/collectors.html?p=1

i didn't find any jquery in the web for that.how can i display like that?.

Comment: why do you need jquery for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't use JavaScript. They just have two versions of each image, a small one and a large one, then they:

```
<a href="document-that-includes-the-large-image.html">
    <img src="the-small-image.jpeg" …>
</a>
```

Comment: I'm going to start naming my files like that :)

Answer (score 0):

in a project where i need to show large image on click of image :-

i pass the big image reference as href  of anchor who i put upon image and show them in fancybox when user click on it.

you can find out fancybox

http://fancybox.net/

the mockup someting like

```
<a href="mybigimage.png"><img src="small.png" alt="small image"/></a>
```